# tarantool java connector & space ids

Tags: tarantool

[Tarantool java connector](https://github.com/tarantool/tarantool-java) provides API to select/update/insert/delete/... tuples in spaces. The first argument in these API methods is a space ID. There is no documentation for this API and I don't clearly undestand how to get these IDs.

The [sample code from github](https://github.com/tarantool/tarantool-java/blob/master/src/test/java/org/tarantool/AbstractTarantoolConnectorIT.java) gets IDs evaluating `box.space.<space>.id` - not using API but directly "writing" command into socket... It seems this is not a good approach (?).

As I see system spaces `_space`/`_vspace` have constant IDs = 280/281. Is it good approach to use these constants to select spaces IDs?

UPD: I found constant `_VSPACE = 281` in the class [SQLDatabaseMetadata](https://github.com/tarantool/tarantool-java/blob/master/src/main/java/org/tarantool/jdbc/SQLDatabaseMetadata.java). It's used in Tarantool JDBC driver. It's protected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right. You need to fetch space id-name mapping from _VSPACE first and then use these values to perform requests against certain spaces. Or you can lean on the fact that a first user-defined space has id 512, then next one 513, etc.

We plan to support automatic schema loading and space names, but don't support it yet: https://github.com/tarantool/tarantool-java/issues/137